# How to create TitleAreaDialog using WTL or Windows SDK (no MFC)?

Tags: c++, windows, sdk, dialog, wtl

I am trying to create a TitleAreaDialog using WTL or Windows SDK (please no MFC). 
From the google I am able to find these two links:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/dialogheader.aspx (MFC article)
2. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/taskdialogs.aspx  (doubtful.. how to use it)

The desired output is like the eclipse JFace TitleAreaDialog (see the below image).

[image: Title Area Dialog]

Kindly suggest a way to do this using sing WTL or Windows SDK (with c++).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally able to solve it using the [Dialog Header](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/dialogheader.aspx) link. Just went through the code twice or may be thrice :) and then ported it for WTL.

There is another very good example in pure c++/win sdk:
[xmessagebox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/xmessagebox.aspx). Its about replacing default windows messagebox with something good (although there is a mode which uses title area + icon).

If working for vista or greater and just want to grab very basic information via checkboxes, radio buttons etc then have a look at this: [Vista_TaskDialog_Wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/Vista_TaskDialog_Wrapper.aspx) and [VGTaskDialog](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/VGTaskDialog.aspx)